# Term buffer font-size

Tags: fonts, spacemacs, term

I am trying to make term buffer to use slightly smaller font than of the rest of Emacs.

I was able to quickly find that for that I need to customize `term` face. I changed the font size, and indeed when the term buffer starts, initially it shows the prompt with the font size I set. But then, once I start typing it falls back to default font-size. Is it possible to get what I want at all?

Let me clarify: I don't want to change font-size with keyboard (which I still can do). I want it to be smaller by default.

**upd:** wondering if I can set `text-scale-mode` on `term-mode-hook`, since I can make it work through customizing the face

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did this:

```
(defun shell-hook ()
   (text-scale-decrease 1.1))

(add-hook 'term-mode-hook 'shell-hook)
```

and it worked beautifully